# Error (TF80068) opening TFS Query from VS2015 to MS Excel

Tags: excel, tfs, visual-studio-2015

We are trying to use the Open in Microsoft Excel feature in VS2015 to open TFS query results in Excel when we receive the error: TF80068: Team Foundation encountered an error while communicating with the server. Please check your connection and try again. [Excel TFS Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBhdI.png)

I can open Excel (Office 365) and use the Team menu New List to connect to the server (2010) and pull the results of the query without issue.

It is only when we use the VS2015 option that it fails.

I've removed and added the AddIn numerous times.
I've tried to register the dll as well...no luck.

Thanks in advance!

[TFS MS Office button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CGZ8.png)

Comment: How to open in Microsoft Excel feature in VS2015 to open TFS query results? Did you mean you try to open some result in Excel through VS2015? Where is the option in VS2015? Could you share the detail step with a screenshot for reproduce the issue?

Comment: - Open VS2015
- Open Team Explorer and select Work Items
- Double click a query 
- Click the Open in Microsoft Office drop down (See pic I added to original question)
- Select Open Query in Microsoft Excel
- Get error

Comment: Thanks for the info.I can't reproduce your issue with VS2015 update2 and TFS2015 update3. Everything just work fine. Did this phenomenon only occurs with your VS or as well as other machines?

Comment: Unfortunately, everyone on our team is experiencing the exact same issue. One thing I did notice from your comment is that we are using TFS 2010 not 2015. Does VS2015 and TFS 2010 not play well? Every other function is working well...just not this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To fix the error open Excel to a blank workbook
2. Click File -> Options -> Add-Ins
3. At the bottom open the Manage drop down and select COM Add-Ins
4. Click Go…
5. In the Add-Ins Available list scroll to the bottom, you should see something like the attached image

[add Ins list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUdvx.png)

6. You may have up to 3 Team Foundation  Add-in items, although they look similar they are different
   a.  Select each one and check the location for each
   b.  Ensure ONLY the one labeled "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Team Foundation Server\14.0\x86\TFSOfficeAdd-in.dll" is selected
7. Verify TFC Office Shim is unselected
8. Click OK
9. Return to VS2015 and open the project in Team Explorer
10. Open Work Items
11. Select Open in Microsoft Office drop down and click Open Query in Microsoft Excel
12. It should now work! You should see data in the worksheet

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should install latest version of Office Integration: [ISO](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691128) and [Web Installer](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691127). 
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I received this error and fixed it by re-signing in using the following steps. There might be a more straight-forward way to fix, but this is what worked for me:

1. Open a new Excel instance.
2. Creat a new workbook.
3. Click on the "Team" tab.
4. Select "New List" ("Connect to Team Foundation Server" dialog should appear)
5. Click "Switch User" in the bottom left.
6. Enter credentials.
7. Open original workbook.