# Excel/TFS integration team sever connection disconnects

Tags: excel, tfs

I am new to excel and TFS integration and I was wondering why does my excel "disconnects" from my TFS server.
When I integrate at first the list cell A1 looks like this:

[image: TFS Connected]

After working for a while and opening and closing the workbook I see that the list is not connected.

[image: TFS disconnected]

Now that its not connected none of my formulas works correctly and my Macro also wont work giving me a error

```
method 'execute' of object '_commandbarbutton' failed
```

Reintegrated with TFS by deleting the entire list and making a new list from TFS, updated my formulas etc.. and the button works fine (When A1) is "blue"

My questions are:

1. How is it disconnected from TFS (What am I doing wrong?)
2. How can I reconnect: I have tried Team > Configure > Server Connection > Reconnect > [OK] and selecting my TFS Server (Does not work)
3. How can I prevent this from happening in the future.

I don't want to delete the entire list again and select Team > New list and do that very time.

Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise

Excel 2016

Comment: Depending on your version of VS you might find a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38646471/error-tf80068-opening-tfs-query-from-vs2015-to-ms-excel

Comment: @ Have you resolved the issue by the solution mentioned in the link above? I tested on my side and cannot reproduce the issue. The connection always working there. Do you have any special settings?

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT - No special settings, I am not sure why it happened and I have not seen it again.

Comment: Got it again after a VBA refresh macro failed.